# Any hacks for zipper that keeps falling down?

Tags: clothing

I just got these jeans that is perfect on me but the zipper keeps on falling down. Can anybody suggest a hack other than using jump rings?

Answer (score 2):

Use a small piece of elastic band or string to create a loop, about 4cm long. 
Attach one end to the lip of the zipper and make it so you can do the loop around your button (Maybe even before closing the button).

Answer (score 1):

I used a small split s-ring through the zipper pull and attached it over the button. Easy to grab, doesn't show, works great.

[image: Split S-ring]
[image: zipper fix]